# How can I format R codes in a 'normal' sentence in LaTeX in the language of R?

Tags: r

I'm new to latex and trying to put my R codes in latex, which I have done in the following way:

```
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
```

To add a block of code I use `start\lstset` and `end\lstset`. But to give an explanation of the codes in a sentence, I want to include some text written in R language. For example in the following sentence, I want sapply dflapop function(x) to appear in R language also in color. How can I do this?

The function `sapply` calls the `dataframe` of the corresponding dataset, which is `dflapop` in this case, and returns a vector conditioned by `function(x)` that sums up all values that are missing.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question; but I t seems to me that you would be best off with packages `minted` and `fancyvrb`. I this there are more suited to your needs.

Comment: Do you know R the package knitr  ? it can execute the R code in a LaTeX  file (with .Rnw extension) , or show it with a highlight  syntax, or both things.  There are many examples of use in this site.

Comment: In addition to Fran's comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr

Answer (score 2):

If you want use `\verb+monofont+` like snippets in text you can use `\lstinline!function(x)!`.